# uncheck all checkboxes on button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table, which get populated from an xml

```
<table id="tableDg" 
    style="border:#2F5882 1px solid;width:100%;"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"> 

    <thead>
     <tr id="trHead" style="color :#FFFFFF;background-color: #8EA4BB" > 
         <th></th>
         <th width="2%"><input id="chkbHead" type='checkbox'  /></th>
         <th width="10%" align="center" spry:sort="name"><b>Name</b></th> 
         <th width="22%" align="center" spry:sort="host"><b>Host</b></th> 

     </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody spry:repeat="pv1">   
     <tr class="trOdd"   
     spry:if="({ds_RowNumber} % 2) != 0" onclick="ds1.setCurrentRow('{ds_RowID}');"
        style="color :#2F5882;background-color: #FFFFFF"> 
         <td><input type="hidden" id="path" value="{path}"></input></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbTest" class = "chkbCsm" ></input></td>
         <td width="10%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" id="nameText" readonly="true" value="{name}"><a href="#" class="aDg">{name}</a></input></td> 
         <td width="22%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" id="nameText" readonly="true" value="{host}">{host}</input></td> 

     </tr> 

     <tr class="trEven" name="trEven" id="trEven"
     spry:if="({ds_RowNumber} % 2) == 0" onclick="ds1.setCurrentRow('{ds_RowID}');"
        style="color :#2F5882;background-color: #EDF1F5;"> 
         <td><input type="hidden" id="path" value="{path}"></input></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class = "chkbCsm" ></input></td>
         <td width="10%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" id="nameText" readonly="true" value="{name}"><a href="#" class="aDg">{name}</a></input></td> 
         <td width="22%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" id="nameText" readonly="true" value="{host}">{host}</input></td> 

     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
```

on button click I am calling a function and inside that function I am doing something like below

```
$('#tableDg input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

but no luck. Help please!! I want to uncheck all the checkboxes on button click

Comment: what console.log($('#tableDg input:checkbox')); is displaying?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I had some error in other part of the page. It works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#tableDg input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
```

Comment: does not work for me; and it doesn't work even if I lowercase the `A`.

Comment: Might have something to do with the Selector. I just copied the selector provided by the OP, but consider giving a class to the checkboxes and using that as the selector.

Comment: Sorry my bad. `$('#tableDg input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');` works too.. I had some error in other part :) So it was not getting reflected

Answer (score 2):

i would use `$('#tableDg input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');`

> Additional Notes:
>   Because :checkbox is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :checkbox cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="checkbox"] instead.

But I assume that the problem is not in the code you used, better provide the script that executes when you click your button

also it seems that your checkboxes do not have value and name attributes, i would recommend you add them if you are using them in forms

also in 1.6 there is a `.removeProp('checked')` but comes with a note

> Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

so your code should be

`$('#tableDg input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);`

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to toggle checkbox status :

```
checked = false;
$('#select_all').click(function() {
  checked = !checked
  $(this).children('input:checkbox').attr('checked', checked);
});
```

Try setting 'checked' to false in your case. Also, try out the same in firebug / chrome inspect's console.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what José Valente said, but you could also check only for checked checkboxes instead of all of them.

```
$('#tableDg input:checked').attr('checked',false);
```

Comment: I am sorry but I have to disagree with you. I uploaded a test here, and it works properly, as it should.

http://isqueel.com/uncheck_all.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably have table in form to handle inputs, so you can use this:

```
$('.my-button').click(
    function(){
        $(this).parents('form').find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Prop instead of using attr

```
$('#tableDg input:checked').prop('checked',false);
```